# warning: no description found for function main using betty compliant syntax

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I'm learning the programming language C and using the Betty coding style of writing C [github.com/holbertonschool/betty](https://github.com/holbertonschool/Betty)),

I have have been getting this syntax warning.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("\n Enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    return (0);
}
```

```
total: 0 errors, 1 warnings, 8 lines checked
c:2: warning: no description found for function main
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've never seen such an error message. Normally functions are not "described" but defined. What compiler are you using? How do you call that compiler and/or the linker?

Comment: Why is this tagged "macbookpro-touch-bar"?

Comment: MSVC gives a similar warning if you omit the `void` argument list. I.e. `int main() {...` gives *warning C4255: 'main': no function prototype given: converting '()' to '(void)'*. But that's not the case in your code.

Comment: Which compiler are you using an dhow are you compiling your program?

Comment: Using a search engine the the error message leads to https://github.com/holbertonschool/Betty/blob/master/betty-doc.pl – which seems to be custom style checker for C programs. It requires your C programs to be formatted and commented in a certain way. Not really a C question. In that case, your teacher/trainer can best give you answers how the code is expected to look.

Answer (score 8):

After including the library, you ought to include a description of the program, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * main - Entry point
 * 
 * Description: 'the program's description'
 * @parameter: describe the parameter
 * 
 * Return: Always 0 (Success)
 */

int main(void)
{
    Code goes here
}
```